# Is there any way to use 'modal' in react navigation so instead of covering the full screen it adapts to the content

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

Currently, I'm using the 'modal' presentation with full height on React Navigation native stack, and I find it visually appealing.

My current implementation:

[image: Current full screen modal]

However, I would like to use it for half the screen or adjust it according to the content height.

A good example is Airbnb's design as shown below:

[image: Airbnb example]

I attempted to set the modal to transparent and the content to flex-end, so it sticks to the bottom while the background is visible. However, this approach looks odd on both Android and iOS platforms.

Unfortunately, I haven't found any other solutions besides creating a native module to use custom native components.

If you have any advice or suggestions, I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:
SlideModal/index.tsx

```
type SlideModalProps = {
  onClose: () => void;
  open: boolean;
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
}

const SlideModal = ({
  onClose,
  open,
  children,
}: SlideModalProps) => (
    <View>
      <Modal
        animationType={Platform.OS === "web" ? "none" : "slide"}
        transparent
        visible={open}
        onRequestClose={onClose}
        onDismiss={onClose}
      >
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
          <BlurView intensity={40} tint="dark" style={styles.blur}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.blurContainer}
              onPress={onClose}
            />
          </BlurView>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <View style={styles.fullWidthContainer}>{children}</View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
```

and styles.ts:

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  centeredView: {
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    alignItems: "center",
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    width: "100%",
    // This is to avoid the animation of the blur background
    height: "200%",
  },
  blurContainer: {
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
  },
  blur: {
    zIndex: 5,
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: "100%",
    flex: 1,
    marginBottom: -14,
  },
  modalView: {
    width: "100%",
    paddingTop: 24,
    paddingBottom: 32,
    alignItems: "center",
    zIndex: 5,
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.white,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: theme.colors.white,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 14,
    borderTopRightRadius: 14,
  },
  fullWidthContainer: {
    width: "100%",
    flexDirection: "column",
  }
});
```

Of course you need to adjust some paddings/margins and the rounding of the elements, but this modal will show up as you want. The trick is to place it outside any container you when it applies the 100% height and width it uses the fullscreen area.